# Not using if(file_exists) bad practice?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, web

I'm working with an upload script for multiple files.  Initially I was checking to see if a file existed and if so appending a unique ID to it and then uploading.

I've since been considering options and decided that I want every file that is uploaded to have the original filename with a unique ID after it.

That then raised the issue of not needing an `if(file_exists)` check so my question is firstly how reliable is `unique()` and is what I'm now doing considered bad practice?

Thanks.

```
//if(file_exists($newPath)){

        $name = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileName = $name . '__' .uniqid().  '.' .$fileExt;
        $newPath = $upload_dir .$newName;
//  }
```

Comment: I would always check for exitence of existing file as well as to make sure in code that the target directory is writable.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used unique but the manual states that it's based off of the current time in microseconds. That can be reliable assuming that nobody creates a file at the same exact microsecond at different sources.

That said, with uniqid() I would use the prefix argument (in the event you deploy this in more than one place) - and it's is highly likely that you'll be fine.

However, I would still do the file_exists check. Performance impact will be completely unnoticeable. I would even go so far as to answer your question as such: yes, it's bad practice not to check to see if a file exists before using that name- particularly when you're writing to a directory that has lots and lots of dynamically created files. In my experience you want to catch EVERY POSSIBLE THING that can mess up your application- and this is a big one. What's to keep somebody from, at some point, throwing a random file in there that just happens to have the same name as a soon-to-be-uniqid()? If the answer is "nothing", then you should absolutely perform the check.

Hope this helps!